# Errors when attempting to install a sharepoint 2010 feature

Tags: 2010, error, feature, feature-activation, cmdlets

I'm attempting to install and activate a feature containing a Timer Job. When I execute the install-spfeature cmdlet I get the following error. What is the source of my error?

```
PS C:\Users\crmadmin> install-spfeature AltirisOpsListFeature
Install-SPFeature : Required tag 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/:Feat
ure' is missing from XML file 'feature.xml', found 'Feature' instead.
At line:1 char:18
+ install-spfeature <<<<  AltirisOpsListFeature
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...tInstallFeature:
SPCmdletInstallFeature) [Install-SPFeature], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletInstallF
eature
```

The feature folder has been added to the 14\Template\Features directory, the Feature.xml file exists and is the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature   xmlns:dm0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/DslTools/Core"         dslVersion="1.0.0.0" Id="58dce6e3-0444-4122-8aa6-08e35345e03e" FeatureId="58dce6e3-0444-4122-8aa6-08e35345e03e" ImageUrl=""     ReceiverAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" ReceiverClass="$SharePoint.Type.bde159bf-eac9-44cd-a06a-df7bfb0e912e.FullName$" Scope="Site" SolutionId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" Title="AltirisOpsListFeature" Version="" DeploymentPath="$SharePoint.Project.FileNameWithoutExtension$_$SharePoint.Feature.FileNameWithoutExtension$" Xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/SharePointTools/FeatureModel" />
```

I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace of your Feature element is wrong. It should be:

> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"

And the next problem you're going to run into if this is how the file looks in SharePointRoot is that a lot of the attributes has tokens that isn't replaced by the real values.

It seems as if the project has been created using the tool from hell (VseWss for VS 2008) and hasn't been upgraded properly see lab for upgrading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/SP2010DevTrainingCourse_UpgradingVSeWSSSolutionsLab)

Answer (score 0):

Per was right, the xmlns was the beginning of my issue(s).

I was just able to install and activate the Timer Job, yea! But, I took a different route than what I did yesterday. Initially, I copied over the feature folder to the product SP2010 hive, and edited and renamed the AltirisFeature1.feature file to Feature.xml. This was incorrect. Though with enough hacking, I was able to get the Feature.xml worthy enough to get installed and activated, the feature subfolder from my vs2010 project did not contain the necessary compiled code of the Timer Job. Yes, i was confused.

To solve my problem, I deactivated and uninstalled the feature from my sp2010 production environment. I then went back into my vs2010 project and added the feature to the package and built the wsp. From there, I loaded and deployed the package to sp2010 using tested scripts. From there, I ran the get-spfeature cmdlet to confirm the feature was added to the farm, and confirmed the name. From there, I activated/enabled the feature using the enable-spfeature cmdlet. success. The timerjob is now running every 5 minutes.

so, Per, thanks for the direction. I have some more learning to do.